# Display images of subcategories with ACF

Tags: wordpress, image, categories, advanced-custom-fields

Help please to display images and titles of subcategories on parent category page. I create field with type "Image", return value "Image URL", rule "Taxonomy is equal to category". I add images for categories. How to display this images with category titles and category links in category.php? I found many samples of code for it, but there are not working. Thanks in advance!

Settings screenshot: https://prnt.sc/17s4x2n

This code shows all Categories, but I need show only subcategories of parent category:

```
<?php
    $categories = get_categories(array('taxonomy'=>'category','hide_empty'=>false));
            if($categories){
                foreach($categories as $cat){?>
                    <div class="cat">
                    <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id);?>"><?php echo $cat->name;?></a></div>
                    <?php if($imgcat=get_field('imgcat', $cat->term_id)){?><div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $imgcat;?>"/></div><?php }?>
            </div>
        <?php }?>
    <?php }?>
```

Comment: Show us the visual form of your settings, and the php code that you use

Comment: Added code and screen of settings

Answer (score 0):

You're almost in the right direction, use the get_field function, please read documentation:

**get_field**($selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);

- $**selector** (string) (Required) The field name or field key.
- $**post_id** (mixed) (Optional) The post ID where the value is saved. Defaults to
  the current post.

Then just use

```
$imgcat=get_field("imgcat", $cat->term_id)
```

```
<?php
    $categories = get_categories(array('taxonomy'=>'category','hide_empty'=>false));
    if(!empty($categories)):
        foreach($categories as $cat):?>
            <div class="cat">
                <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id);?>"><?php echo $cat->name;?></a></div>
                <?php if($imgcat_src=get_field('imgcat', $cat->term_id)):?>
                <div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $imgcat_src;?>"/></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                    $taxonomies = array( 
                        'category',
                    );
                    $args = array(
                        'parent'         => $cat->term_id
                    ); 
                    $subcategories = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
                ?>
                <?php
                if(!empty(subcategories)): ?>
                <div class="subcats">
                    // foreach -> get_field()
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Still doesn't working( No images. And I need to show only child categories of current parent category. Edited code is in first post.

Comment: see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13487/193674

Comment: Thanks. But... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' here: 'parent' => $cat->term_id;

Comment: Now Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)
for line where <?php endforeach; ?>
)

Comment: Now show all categories (don't showing images) and this: Warning: Use of undefined constant subcategories - assumed 'subcategories' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) https://prnt.sc/17t6ay0

Comment: // foreach -> get_field() - this is comment for you, you have to replace it with your code, go through the subcategories and display everything you need, I will not write all the code for you